# Power Automate condition shown as false when its correct

Tags: json, if-statement, power-automate, power-platform

Its my first time posting and very new in IT so sorry for the easy questions.

**1. Show false when condition should be correct/match.**

I used Microsoft Power automate trying to extract a row from an Excel workbook and input it to another workbook (And make some edits after input but that is the second part of the question.)
This is my flow (Screenshots with raw input are below)

1. Set trigger
2. Select the target excel file/ aka source.
3. "apply to each" action tag
4. Set condition-> if "move" column in excel shows as "move"
5. If yes, move that row of data.
6. If not, do nothing (No action set in the "if no" tag

The issue is that even if I set the value as "Move" in the "Move column", also checked the raw data to confirm it is shown as Move on excel, the "expression result" is shown as false. Yet, data still get moved after a few minutes, despite the system showing it didn't go down the "if yes" tag and that part is "No action required"

**Step 2**

[image: Step 2]

**Issue**

[image: Issue]

**2. Due to that issue, the further detailed edit I want to make after data is put into new Workbook is not valid and the whole flow becomes incorrect.**

[image: Issue]

I try to use the "update row" action to make detailed further edits after the whole row is imported.

The condition tag error message is mainly in Japanese but it says "ActionConditionFailed. This condition was skipped, the action prior was not executed, the expected value was succeeded, but the value was Skipped"

I tried to read the raw data provided but it didn't show as much as I hoped.

let me know how I can make my question easier to understand also!
Thank you so much!

[Value screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ABz6.png)
[Condition screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpI2J.png)

Comment: Can you show your condition action with the relevant values that are being compared?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I set the condition to be-> if the "test-Move to SetupList" column in excel is "Move to SetupList" (made a drop-down list on excel for users), then it would be the data being extracted to the other excel workbook.